# JasperReports - state name on y axis of time series chart

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have built a time series chart in jasperreports studio with the followin dataset:

```
"status" : [
            {"value": 0, "timestamp":"16:30:07"},
            {"value": 0, "timestamp":"17:31:07"},
            {"value": 1, "timestamp":"18:32:07"},
            {"value": 1, "timestamp":"19:33:07"},
            {"value": 1, "timestamp":"20:34:07"},
            {"value": 1, "timestamp":"21:35:07"},
            {"value": 2, "timestamp":"22:36:07"},
            {"value": 0, "timestamp":"23:37:07"}
        ]
```

and it works fine.

Now, I wanted to "translate" my value field on my dataset to 0 - Off, 1-Middle, 2-On and show that info on my y-axis.

The end result should be like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Does anyone know how can this be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jfreechart @AlexK

Comment: Perhaps [`SymbolAxis`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SymbolAxis).

Comment: Can it be done using only JasperStudio?

Comment: Sorry, not a [tag:jasper-reports] user, but the `SymbolAxis` keyword may help refine your search.